# TMNT2014: What did Splinter hide before fighting Shredder

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In the movie, as he gears up to face off against Shreder, Splinter picks up something (possibly a book) with his tail and hides it under the platform he's standing on.  It happens about 25 seconds into this clip.

What did he hide?

Comment: They are his shoes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrub back a few more seconds. Splinter is removing his [geta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geta_%28footwear%29) (or possibly just sandals, it's a little tough to see for sure) and placing them out of the way.

[image: figure image]

Comment: Well spotted, thanks :)