# 70s/80s ninja/martial arts movie with a Korean ninja and enemies having a flying fortress/castle

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the late early 1990s, I saw a few minutes of a 1970s/1980s Ninja Movie (not a cartoon or anime, a live action film) on a cheap local UHF TV station.

The movie in question has the following elements:

1. Had a late 70's, early 80's Ninja Movie feel, both dialogue and plot badly dubbed over the original Asian content
2. The most striking feature was the bad guys had a flying fortress, a castle build on some kind of floating mountain - you would think this would be a dead giveaway, but a recent Anime claims the first 500 search results for related terms.
3. When each major character was introduced, the scene would pause with a freeze frame of that person in action, with the background colored out and that persons name printed on the screen. I distinctly remember the narrator saying "...THE KOREAN NINJA...(name forgotten)" for one of the characters.
4. The Korean Ninja wore wooden sandals, that resembled a rectangular block of wood, with two smaller rectangular pieces of wood affixed to the bottom as a sole.

Comment: Are you saying this was anime or at least animated? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Your 4th point describes [Geta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geta_(footwear)) which are ubiquitous among ninja masters, even [Master Splinter wears them](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102195/tmnt2014-what-did-splinter-hide-before-fighting-shredder)

Comment: There must literally be thousands of badly dubbed ninja movies from the 70s/80s. The flyng fortress really isn't enough to help us find it. Can you remember anything else?

Comment: @Daft, I really cannot remember anything else. There cannot be that many ninja movies with a Flying Castle, can there? Also, my original question with background information as to why I cannot remember more was edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably *Sanada Yukimura no bouryaku* (1979), also known as *Renegade Ninjas*,  *The Shogun Assassins* or *Death of the Shogun*.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165218/):

> Generel Sanada, seeking retribution for the murder of his father and a lost battle, both conceived by the Shogun, devises a series of brilliant plans to thwart the Shogun's overwhelming strength.

The movie revolves around the [Sanada Ten Braves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanada_Ten_Braves), and they all get their freeze-frame introduction. Most notably, "the Korean Ninja, Isa Miyoshi" is introduced at 10:30. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0kVg.png) in case the link goes dead. Other ninja introductions at 7:59 and 10:49 for instance.

As for the flying fortress, there is one descending upon the troops at 1:24:50, better seen at 1:25:15. Once again, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZfF3.png).

And the dubbing is indeed as awful as you can get.

**Warning: some female nudity (girl and woman bathing, and a guy handling the latter's breasts).** Also, did I mention awful dubbing?

---

Found with the Google query `movie "the korean ninja" transcript -chiun` which yielded [this identification request on a Kung-Fu fandom forum](http://www.shaolinchamber36.com/kungfufandom/index.php?/topic/12130-what-is-this-ninja-movie/&tab=comments#comment-141792). The `-chiun` is there to exclude [*Remo Williams: The Adventure Begins*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089901/) which was the result of my first query (`movie "the korean ninja" transcript`).

Comment: Fair warning, based on my poking around in the movie, there is female nudity in a river bathing scene, both a woman and a girl, not sexual, but you may want to be careful where you watch it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for the heads-up, they're a bit closer just before that, edited the warning in